# Use an imported class without specifying the package in JSP

Tags: class, jsp, import, package

In my JSP I have

```
<%@ page import "com.example.Elenco" %>
```

but inside a very small scriptlet, whenever i try to instantiate Elenco, it requires the full name.

If i write

```
Elenco a = new Elenco(blabla);
```

Eclipse gives the following error: "Elenco cannot be resolved to a type", and I have to write

```
com.example.Elenco a = new com.example.Elenco(blabla);
```

that is pretty uncomfortable. Do exist any method to make the package name not mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import directive seems to be wrong. Try

```
<%@ page import="com.example.Elenco" %>
```

You are missing the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
<%@ page import="com.example.Elenco" %>
               ^--- you need an equal sign here
```